# Alternate naming for a logger?

Tags: logging, naming

I have just started working in a company involved in the wood industry.  Does anybody have any good alternate naming so that I can differentiate between the logging that is printing to the console and the logging that is cutting down trees?

Comment: I don't know what to say to this question. Maybe just LOL! You could use tracing (even though tracing is a not quite the same). Alternatively you could use application logging or program logging.

Comment: I don't know, diary, journal ? :)

Comment: Hmm, yeah I might just qualify it as an ApplicationLog and figure out a way to make sure the word 'log' never appears alone.

Comment: Probably a better fit for http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the naming of something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Record
- Trace
- Archive
- Note
- Entry

[More words that may be similar](http://thesaurus.com/browse/logging).

Comment: +1 for pointing out that what I need is a thesaurus.  I'm not finding anything synonyms that I really like though...